# AudioUnit is not working in 10.6

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, backwards-compatibility, audiounit

I'm using Osx 10.7 with Xcode 4.2.1, my AU plug-in works well in 10.7 but is not running in 10.6. When I try to change the Base SDK from 10.7 to 10.6 I get errors in the AUBase.h, ComponantBase.h and AUPluginDispatch.h

Maybe I need to switch my CoreAudio files to 10.6?

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always set the Base SDK to "Current Mac OS", and then the Mac OS X Deployment Target to the lowest version you plan to support. The CoreAudio SDK shouldn't make a difference in this case.